# Trying to make use array.clear() but Index was outside the bounds of the array keeps popping out when I run the program?

Tags: c#, arrays

So I'm trying to code a button to make it clear an array when the code entered matches the productcode . However , this error (Index was outside the bounds of the array) keeps popping out when I try to run the program .. Here's the code I used :

```
        string code;
        code = txtcode.Text;

        for (int i = 0; i < compartmentno.Length; i++)
        {
            if (productcode[i] == code)
            {
                Array.Clear(compartmentno, i, compartmentno.Length);
                Array.Clear(productcode, i, productcode.Length);
                Array.Clear(name, i, name.Length);
                Array.Clear(weight, i, weight.Length);
                Array.Clear(address, i, address.Length);
                Array.Clear(status, i, status.Length);
            }
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong ? Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: you are clearing the entire rest of the array when you have a match; doesnt bode well for iteration i+1

Answer (score 3):

Because the third parameter indicates the number of elements to clear, you are passing the size of the entire array.

You only need `Array.Clear(compartmentno, i, 1)`, as **it seems like** there is one element you wish to clear. It would be helpful if you could explain more about what this code is supposed to do.

Also, instead of using six associated arrays, consider creating a class to store your information:

```
class ProductInfo
{
    public string CopmartmentNo { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.Clear` attempts to clear an array from one index for a *length*.  When you use it starting at 0 there is no problem.  However, when you start at 1 you go past the end of your array.

Answer (score 0):

you're only comparing your iterator `i` against the size of the `compartmentno` array, which may not have the same size as the other arrays. Use `if` statements to check before clearing.

```
if(i < ___.Length) Array.Clear(___, i, ___.Length);
```

Furthermore, the [`Array.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) method states that the first parameter is the starting index, and the second is he number of elements toclear, *not* the ending index. Thus, this code will fail any time `i` is greater than `0`. Use `___.Length - i` instead to trim down the value and prevent that out-of-bounds-

```
if(i < ___.Length) Array.Clear(___, i, ___.Length - i);
```

thus:

```
for (int i = 0; i < compartmentno.Length; i++)
        {
            if (productcode[i] == code)
            {
                if(i < compartmentno.Length) Array.Clear(compartmentno, i, compartmentno.Length - i);
                if(i < productcode.Length) Array.Clear(productcode, i, productcode.Length - i);
                if(i <  name.Length) Array.Clear(name, i, name.Length - i);
                if(i < wight.Length) Array.Clear(weight, i, weight.Length - i);
                if(i < address.Length) Array.Clear(address, i, address.Length - i);
                if(i < status.Length) Array.Clear(status, i, status.Length - i);
            }
```